# Android List View with multiple items displaying them horizontally

Tags: list, view

I have a list view in my activity and it is getting some items from database like `Name,Played Games,Games won`. 
Now i'm displaying these items in a list view

I want to design like this

```
Name  Games Played  Games won    
XXX        5            3
```

But after running the application it looks like this

```
Name  Games Played  Games won

XXX

5

3

XXX

8

5
```

So i want to display these three values in a same list item horizontally,Please help me

```
List<String> score = new ArrayList<String>();
    db=this.openOrCreateDatabase("Hangman",MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    c=db.rawQuery("Select name,gamesplayed,gameswon from users",null);
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            String usr=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
            String played=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("gamesplayed"));
            String won=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("gameswon"));
            score.add(usr);
            score.add(played);
            score.add(won);

        }while(c.moveToNext());
 }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adptr= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row,R.id.member_name,score);
    lv1.setAdapter(adptr);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display them horizontally then you just make a cocatenated string and add it only once

String val=usr + "" + played +........;

score.add(val);

Comment: the logic works fine but the alignment is not fixed according to the length of the name values are been overflowed.

Comment: Then you will have to arrange those variables by adding spaces or any other characters in it. and I you feel my ans was useful then please click on the tickmark.

Comment: i have added spaces and aligned them but if name is big then the alignment is going out of flow.i want it as fixed

Comment: if your name is to big then you should get a substring of that and then display it. The users can understand depending on sub string. Or you could displayeach information on different line like `Name  - XXX
Games Played - 5
Games won - 3
`

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom list view adapter, http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown provides a good tutorial